# GetElementsByName в HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Получаю я скриптом элементы с некоторым именем:

```
        var arr = document.getElementsByName("E");
```

хочу получить значения этих элементов, но почему-то arr[0] не имеет свойства value либо другого, хоть на всех доках нет, искал по HTML5 тоже пусто, как можно теперь получить значения т.е. value этих элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `value` есть только у элементов `input`, `select` и `textarea`. Ну может еще `button`. В Вашем случае надо использовать

```
console.log(arr[0].getAttribute("value"));
```

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByName("testname");
console.log(arr[0].getAttribute("value"));
```

```html
<div name="testname" value="testvalue">TEST DIV with name and value</div>
```